# How to install TensorFlow on Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, raspberry-pi2, python-wheel

I'm trying to install TensorFlow on a Raspberry Pi 2 with Raspian Lite OS installed on and a 8 Gb SD card. I'm using Python version 2.7.9 and I'm trying to install TensorFlow for it.
I previously searched and tried to solve the problem by me but couldn't do it.
Already followed these guides:

1. TensorFlow Official Guide
2. IotMakerBlog guide
3. Sam J Abrahams guide on GitHub

I have also read a lot of solutions proposed in some other Stack Overflow questions, but the problem is always the same:

```
 tensorflow-1.1.0-cp27-none-linux_armv7l.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

This happens everytime I try to download the .whl and use pip to install it. Moreover, if I try to use pip directly, the error I get is the following:

```
# pip install tensorflow
Collecting tensorflow
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

I also tried with pip2 as suggested in some guides and I also tried to install the Python 3 version. The result is the same as here.

Could anyone help me? Many thanks.

Comment: Just adding links to the guides mentioned above: 1. https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux ; 2. https://iotmakerblog.wordpress.com/2017/01/28/installing-testing-tensorflow-on-raspberry-pi2/ ; 3. https://github.com/samjabrahams/tensorflow-on-raspberry-pi

Comment: EDIT: I was actually seeing that the Raspberry has armv6l but it seems that armv7l is required. Is it true? And why?

Comment: use my dockerfile.. [pi-tensorflow-docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/kranthivolt/tensorflow-pillow-boto3/tags/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end I found that the problem was the processor. Indeed, with Raspbian it is considered to be ARMv6 but it is ARMv7. So, changing OS to Ubuntu MATE did the trick. Now I have installed TensorFlow on my Pi.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this:

First, install the dependencies for TensorFlow:

```
sudo apt-get update

# For Python 2.7
sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev

# For Python 3.3+
sudo apt-get install python3-pip python3-dev
```

Next, download the wheel file from this repository and install it:

```
# For Python 2.7
wget https://github.com/samjabrahams/tensorflow-on-raspberry-pi/releases/download/v1.1.0/tensorflow-1.1.0-cp27-none-linux_armv7l.whl
sudo pip install tensorflow-1.1.0-cp27-none-linux_armv7l.whl

# For Python 3.4
wget https://github.com/samjabrahams/tensorflow-on-raspberry-pi/releases/download/v1.1.0/tensorflow-1.1.0-cp34-cp34m-linux_armv7l.whl
sudo pip3 install tensorflow-1.1.0-cp34-cp34m-linux_armv7l.whl
```

Finally, we need to reinstall the mock library to keep it from throwing an error when we import TensorFlow:

```
# For Python 2.7
sudo pip uninstall mock
sudo pip install mock

# For Python 3.3+
sudo pip3 uninstall mock
sudo pip3 install mock
```

See more details from [tensorflow-on-raspberry-pi](https://github.com/samjabrahams/tensorflow-on-raspberry-pi).

Comment: Thank you for answering but you should read the question first. As I wrote I already tried the guide by Sam J Abrahams on GitHub and it didn't work.

Comment: Yes, it works with 64 bit architectures but Raspberry Pi, as far as I know, has 32 bit architecture. https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/34715/is-raspbian-for-the-raspberry-pi-2-b-32-bit-or-a-64-bit-os

Answer (score 0):

@all, I noticed that you were trying to have tensorflow running on Raspberry Pi 2. If you are willing to try tensorflow lite on Raspberry Pi 3 as well, my  "pull-request" may be useful. My contribution is at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/24194.

Following my steps, 2 apps to get your own development started, label_image and camera, can run on Raspberry Pi 3.

Best,

--Jim

Answer (score -1):

Miniconda (Anaconda) can install python 3.4 with a version of pip that can upgrade to the latest pip which can install tensorflow-1.11.0-cp34 as well as keras wheels for the Arm processor:

```
wget http://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-armv7l.sh
bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-armv7l.sh
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install tensorflow keras
```