# Error when importing tensorflow on raspberry pi 2

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, raspberry-pi

After installing tensorflow from the source on my raspberry pi, importing tensorflow gives me the following error:

```
import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
```

By the way, I am installing from the official tensorflow website on a raspberry pi 2 on python 3.4.
I uninstalled all of the tensorflow dependencies including numpy, and installed. This installed all of the dependencies but took around an hour. It also said that:

```
Could not find .egg-info directory in install record for numpy>=1.11.0 (from tensorflow==1.2.0)
```

and:

```
 Could not find .egg-info directory in install record for protobuf
```

Then when importing tensorflow, it gives me the first error.

Answer (score 0):

You error `_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64` means that you're trying to load 64-bit code into 32-bit process. 
What OS do you have? 
This [guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43734513/how-to-install-tensorflow-on-raspberry-pi-2) was succeeded in installing tensorflow on Raspberry Pi 2.
You can also try [this package](https://github.com/samjabrahams/tensorflow-on-raspberry-pi).
Note that running Raspberry 2 is not straightforward task. What official tensorflow site did you use?

As for egg-info warnings, try to upgrade setuptools with `pip install --upgrade setuptools pip`.